PDF not recognizing Bookmarks when Html converted to pdf using IText7
I want to create bookmarks in a PDF document that is being converted via IText7.  When parsing the html string data using HtmlConverter.convertToElements it does not pick up  tags. The  designation seems to be imbedded in the child element of the child element of a  tag.  Note: the html doesn't even include a  tag.  This seems to be created by the HtmlConverter.
This is the java code being used
    List<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(pdfData, properties);
 
    for (IElement element : elements) {
      if (element instanceof HtmlPageBreak)
        doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
     else
       doc.add((IBlockElement) element);
    }

The html file looks something like:
<body>

      <h1>BookMark 1</h1>
<p>
    <H4>Company: </H4>
    <H4>Date:  </H4>
</p>

<table  width="100%">
     <tr>
     <th align="center" width="16%">Company</th>
`   </tr>
     
     <tbody> <tr><td width ="16%" align="center">test1</td></tr></tbody>
</table>


I am able to find the  tag by doing this:
  divElement = (Div) element; 
          divElement.getAccessibilityProperties().getRole().startsWith("H");

but then I do not know how to add it to the doc so that PDF will recognize as a  tag and therefore create a bookmark in the PDF.
